# AngularJS .bootstrap() and Modules

Tags: angularjs

I'm having a problem, I need to load a module in the angular.boostrap and not before it but angular keeps loading it before I tell to load it.

**Here I call the angular.boostrap method, this function is called as a callback of GMaps api so I know this is working because of the console.log**

```
function onGoogleReady() {
  console.log("GMaps api initialized.");
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('map', ['app.ui.map']));
}
```

**and this is my module:**

```
angular.module('myAppModule', ['ui.map'])
.controller('CtrlGMap', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.500, -78.500),
        zoom: 11,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
}]);
```

**and finally my app HTML**

```
<html ng-app="myAppModule">
```

```
<section id="map">
    <div ui-map="myMap" ui-options="mapOptions" class="map-canvas"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ng-app` directive bootstraps your application. If you want to bootstrap it manually, you should not use `ng-app`. `angular.bootstrap` also takes the *root* module to bootstrap; in this case, this is your `myAppModule` module (which already depends on `ui.map` because of the `angular.module` definition). Thus, your code would look more like the following:

```
function onGoogleReady() {
  console.log("GMaps api initialized.");
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  angular.bootstrap(body, ['myAppModule'])
}
```